# Is there an expression involving a variable $x$ that evaluates to $1$ when $x = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well, the question is pretty much in the title so... I guess I'll just elaborate.

Specifically, the value of the expression should either be $1$ ($x = 0$) or $0$ (when $x \neq 0$).

Does this exist?

(I just tagged this as `algebra-precalculus` because I don't know what tag to use; feel free to change it because I realize that it's not the most appropriate tag ever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinions differ, but I would answer $0^{|x|}$.

The issue come from the conflict of two rules: "0 to any positive power is 0", and "Anything to the 0th power is 1." The question then is: what is the value of $0^0$? Many people leave it undefined; some benighted souls think it is 0; but good-looking and well-informed people know it is 1. This is because it is an empty product, whose value is the multiplicative identity (the same reason why $0! = 1$.) It is bolstered by the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x = 1$.

So $0^{|x|}$ is 0, unless $x = 0$, in which case it is 1.

A more standard way to discuss this is with the
[Kronecker delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), denoted $\delta_{ij}$ (or sometimes $\delta_i^j$, or $\delta(i,j)$, etc.), which is 1 if $i = j$ and 0 otherwise.
So you are looking for $\delta_{0x}$, which is sometimes abbreviated (as the Wikipedia article notes) as just $\delta_x$, and is sometimes referred to as the *unit impulse function*.

Comment: Using limits to argue that $0^0=1$ doesn't seem a good idea to me, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^0=1$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}0^x=0$, which is why $0^0$ is indeterminate when evaluating a limit, it is however just equal to $1$ in the other cases

Comment: @Alessandro: $\lim_{x\to 0} 0^x$ is undefined in any case, since it's invalid for negative $x$, so any definition of $0^0$ is the same as far as that goes. The fact that $x^0$ does continue into the negatives, and requires $0^0 = 1$ to be continuous, is another argument in its favor. However, I view all this, as I described it, as ancillary evidence: the _reason_ is that the empty product is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)
 of the set $\{0\}$.

The indicator function of a subset $A$ of a set $X$ is a function
$$
\mathbf{1}_A \colon X \to \{ 0,1 \}
$$
defined as
$$
\mathbf{1}_A(x)=
\begin{cases} 
1 &\text{if } x \in A, \\
0 &\text{if } x \notin A.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Isn't it the case that the evaluation of such a function requires already knowing whether or not the argument is 0?

Comment: @Stan We need to know the argument if we want to evaluate the function. The value of the indicator function of the set $\{0\}$ is equal to $1$ if the argument is equal to $0$ and the value is equal to $0$ otherwise. I hope this helps.